# Accepted offer letter, no communication from their side; what steps can I take?

Tags: communication, job-offer, new-job, hiring-process, india

I accepted offer letter from a investment banking company and the joining date is next week.

I completed my background verification and they have sent a RSA token to start work from home. This was 2 weeks ago.

Now, I don't receive any communication from the company regarding joining, even HR doesn't pick up the call.

Three days ago I asked them about the updates on receiving laptop/visiting the office on joining date but there was no reply.

I still need to provide service completion certificate (Relieving Letter) from the present company which I will receive on next Friday.

What steps could I take in order to sort these things out?

Comment: They gave you the RSA token, but have they assigned you any tasks yet? Or are you just hanging there without any tasks been given to you? Also, what sort of contact have you tried? (emails? phone calls?). Could it be they are on vacations already?

Comment: Also, did they give you a contract and you both signed it? Or just the offer letter? Was the letter in writing I guess?

Comment: Maybe because it is holidays period, be patient until your starting day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 4):

Telephonic conversations are unofficial. All of your communication has to be through an email. Drop an email requesting for the joining formalities etc. Maintain a mail chain. Wait for their response. Give a buffer time of a week and if you still do not get any response, then drop a gentle reminder.

These are the steps you can take. You cannot force them to reply to your email. Keep your job hunt in progress.

Answer (score 1):

> *What steps could I take in order to sort these things out?*

In the below order, do these **now**:

1. If you have the contact number of the recruitment team / your reporting manager/ HR, **call them up** and enquire about the status.
2. If you do not have a direct contact number, find out some general communication number (from website/ previous emails), **call them** and ask to be connected to the department handing the joining process.
3. Send a very clear email with all the relevant people marked asking about the joining process, formalities and the contract signing.

**One thing to highlight**: If you have not signed and submitted a work contract, there's no contract, irrespective of what other activities might have happened. They should send a copy of the contract for you to review, sign and submit before you're actually an employee of the company. Some companies do not send the contract in advance and get formalities done on the joining day itself, but at least having that confirmed over email is a good thing.